# How to write unit test for Elasticsearch painless scripts using Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Here is my sample painles script used in Elasticsearch. I want to write a unit test for this. How can I achieve it?

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
       for(param in params.entrySet()) {
         ctx.source.put(param.getKey(), param.getValue())
      }
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "sold_cost": 26
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to test is to use docker to bring up an elasticsearch instance, setup indices with seed data, and run tests using the scripts.
We found additional benefits of the DB setup scripts being tested on a new ES instance.
Downside is its slower because its integration tests, and slows down the CI pipeline. But better than deploying manually tested code with string scripts.